# crawl-300d-2M-subword.zip corrupted or cannot be downloaded

Tags: fasttext

I am trying to use this `fasttext` model [crawl-300d-2M-subword.zip](https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/fasttext/vectors-english/crawl-300d-2M-subword.zip) from the official page onI my Windows machine, but the download fails by the last few Kb.

I managed to successfully download the zip file into my ubuntu server using `wget`, but the zipped file is corrupted whenever I try to unzip it. Example of what I am getting:

```
unzip crawl-300d-2M-subword.zip
Archive:  crawl-300d-2M-subword.zip
  inflating: crawl-300d-2M-subword.vec
  inflating: crawl-300d-2M-subword.bin   bad CRC ff925bde  (should be e9be08f7)
```

It is always the file `crawl-300d-2M-subword.bin`, which I am interested in, that has problems in te unzipping.

I tried the two ways many times but with no success. it seems to me no one had this issue before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just downloaded & unzipped that file with no errors, so the problem is likely unique to your system's configuration, tools, or its network-path to the download servers.

One common problem that's sometimes not prominently reported by a tool like `wget` is a download that keeps ending early, resulting in a truncated local file.

- Is the zip file you received exactly 681,808,098 bytes long? (That's what I get.)
- What if you try another download tool instead, like `curl`? (Such a relay between different endpoints might not trigger the same problems.)

Sometimes if repeated downloads keep failing in the same way, it's due to subtle misconfiguration bugs/corruption unique to the network path from your machine to the peer (download origin) machine.

- Can you do a successful download of the zip file (of full size per above) to anywhere else?
- Then, transfer from that secondary location to where you really want it?

If you're having problems on both a Windows machine, and a Ubuntu server, are they both on the same local network, perhaps subject to the same network issues – either bugs, or policies that cut a particular long download short?

Comment: I am indeed behind my company proxy, which might be the reason. As you have mentioned, the size of the zip I download each time is around 5,828,35*,***. I used `curl` but the download didn't finish appropriately with a `curl: (18) transfer closed with 1100 bytes remaining to read` message. I will try another network and/or another machine.

Comment: If it's not exactly 681,808,098 bytes, you're not getting the full file. It certainly sounds like something unique to your network is interrupting this download before finish – causing an error that might not be sufficiently prominent in `wget`. This could be triggered by length, by patterns within the transfer, or other more arbitrary things. (IIUS, occasionally network hardware can even malfunction such that certain rare bit patterns always get a tiny amounf of corruption in the exact same way, causing repeatable problems on just the very-rare data & path-to-remote-peer combos that trigger.)

Comment: So: in addition to workarounds like other systems/multi-hop paths, you could report as a reproducible mystery to your company's IT/network staff - though it would likely take a very senior/curious/deep-into-the-details expert to dig into the rarest/weirdest possible causes of such a problem, such as a single flaky-silicon or misconfigured network unit.

Comment: One other belated thought: occasionally such mysterious path/file/network-combo oddities can be worked-around by forcing a different, unnaturally-small "MTU" (max size for network packets). Essentially, by ensuring the data is chopped up slightly differently, & in packets sure to be far under any interim network hop limits, some prior bad-luck/bad-network-hop errors get dodged. See for example <https://linuxhint.com/how-to-change-mtu-size-in-linux/> for ways to temporarily try lower values, like say `1400` or even `400`, on your Ubuntu server.

Comment: I managed to download the file successfully by disconnecting from the company proxy. I will definitely report this, and eventually, try your suggestion about changing the MTU of the network to check if it is the reason.